# What is the best way for storing and versioning his aliases/functions/symlinks?

Tags: bash, zsh, alias, rc, bash-functions

actually I have these lines (exemplary) in my `.zshrc` file:

```
. ${TOOLS_HOME}/cli/.cli_base
. ${TOOLS_HOME}/cli/.cli_functions
. ${TOOLS_HOME}/cli/.cli_symlinks
```

This works fine so far. My only problem is, that in these `.cli_xxx` files I don't have syntax highlighting (For aliases this is ok - but for functions this is very hard).
So I tried this one:

```
. ${TOOLS_HOME}/cli/cli_base.sh
. ${TOOLS_HOME}/cli/cli_functions.sh
. ${TOOLS_HOME}/cli/cli_symlinks.sh
```

But (as I red over google) the `.` is like `source` and when I source my `.zshrc` file and execute an alias I sometimes get this error message:

```
bash:30: maximum nested function level reached
```

Thats because of the "multi source"??
Somebody have like a "best practice" for storing and versioning aliases/functions/symlinks or do I have to stay with my `.cli_xxxx` files??

Comment: If the only issue is syntax highlighting, then this should not affect what you call your files. Instead, figure out how you can signal to your editor what syntax highlighting it should use from within the file itself.  What editor are you using?

Comment: actually mostly I use atom - so you say this is the right way what I am doing (with dotfiles)?

Comment: Well, you say that you have something that works. Why break it for the sake of syntax highlighting? Unfortunately I've never used Atom, so I can't really say whether it support modelines, but that's what this feature is usually called. A quick search gave me https://atom.io/packages/modeline

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, that the issue is completely unrelated to the name of the files would also happen if you sourced `.zshrc` in the original state.

#### Cause of the error

This error usually happens when you call a function from within itself, leading to a recursion. This may inadvertently happen, when you give functions the same name as an external command or builtin that is used within that function. For example:

```
echo () {
    echo "Out: " $@
}
```

The command `echo` will work just fine, before you define this function, but after the definition it will fail with this error:

```
% echo foobar
echo:1: maximum nested function level reached; increase FUNCNEST?
```

(The difference in the message text is probably due to the zsh versions used, which in my case is 5.6.2)

It can also happen through multiple functions calling each other:

```
foo () {
    echo $@
}

echo () {
    something_else
    foo $@
}
```

The error message will show the name of the function that cannot be called anymore due to the nesting limit being reached and the line of the function where this call happens. So in the above case either:

```
% echo foobar
echo:1: maximum nested function level reached; increase FUNCNEST?
```

or

```
% echo foobar
foo:2: maximum nested function level reached; increase FUNCNEST?
```

In the case of the question it seems that a function with the name `bash` is called in line 30 of some function.

#### Fixing it

Unless the recursion is intentional, this can be prevented by telling `zsh` which non-function command you want to use.

- If you want the built-in command, just prepend `builtin`:

  ```
  echo ()
  {
      builtin echo "Out: " $@
  }
  ```
- If you want an external command, either prepend `command`:

  ```
  echo ()
  {
      command echo "Out: " $@
  }
  ```

  or use its full path

  ```
  echo ()
  {
      /bin/echo "Out: " $@
  }
  ```

If you are not sure where you are using `bash` in your `zsh` configuration, you can use `grep` to search `${TOOLS_HOME}/cli/` recursively:

```
grep -r bash ${TOOLS_HOME}/cli/
```