# colorssh:7: maximum nested function level reached; increase FUNCNEST?

Tags: terminal, osx, zsh, iterm2

I got the following message when trying to ssh into a server using iterm2 in macosx

```
colorssh:7: maximum nested function level reached; increase FUNCNEST?
```

When using terminal app it worked fine. Not sure where it is coming from. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you recently set up a script called `colorssh`? Did you recently edit any of your shell startup files (`~/.zshrc`, for instance)?

Comment: Relating - similar error: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493397/117549

Comment: I dont see any script names colorssh. since it works in the terminall app and not in iterm2 makes me think somehow they are loading some different configuration. but not sure exactly what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with `zsh-256color` plugin.

The plugin is supposed to colorize zsh output. For some reason it fails for ssh.

Removed it and it works fine now.